# Cannot update shortcut (folder name with space) in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Why do I get error "Value does not fall within the expected range."

```
# Path to the shortcut you want to change
$shortcutPath = "C:\folder with space\terminal.exe - Portable.lnk"

# New EXE target path
$newTargetPath = """C:\folder with space\terminal.exe""  /portable"


$shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Location = "C:\folder with space\"
$shortcut = $shell.CreateShortcut("$Location\terminal.exe - Portable.lnk")
$shortcut.TargetPath = $newTargetPath 
#$shortcut.IconLocation = "shell32.dll,21"
$shortcut.Save()
```

Comment: Only the _executable path_ goes into `.TargetPath`; any _arguments_ to pass to it go into `.Arguments`. 
 This contrasts with creating a shortcut file _interactively_: In the Properties dialog presented by the Windows shell (File Explorer), the single `Target` field is a _concatenation_ of these two underlying properties; that is, in the GUI you specify only _one_ value - the entire command line - which is then split into executable name/path and arguments behind the scenes.
 See the linked duplicate for details.